# Is there a way we can classify between chest xray and not chest xray using keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to deep learning and recently have been trying out some codes in Keras to develop a pneumonia classification program which uses a dataset that contains chest x-ray images. But before even using that program I want to add another layer of classification that will detect if the uploaded image is a chest Xray or not. If the uploaded image is a chest x-ray then only the pneumonia classification code will trigger or else it will show an error. 
As of now the code I am using for pneumonia classification accepts any kind of images, be it chest x-ray or an image of a dog or a cat and as such gives a prediction no matter what. So, I wanted to know if there is a way we can classify the uploaded image is a chest x-ray or an image of something else.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  But probably better suited for Data Science Stack Exchange? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks. Will check it out.